# Laravel Model nested query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I was trying to write a single query to get full user diet from database. The problem is that I am not able to get data from the **diet_food** table. Here are my tables:

- **diet_settings** (*id, total_days, etc*). The basic information about the users diet.
- **eating_types** (*id, diet_id, eating_time, etc*). Information about breakfast, lunch etc.
- **diet_food** (*id, eating_type_id, product, etc*). Food related to each eating type.

This is the query that I use in my controller class:

```
$diet = Diet::with("eatingType.dietFood")->get()->find($id)->toArray();
```

So when I use **var_dump()** this is what it looks like:

```
array (size=7)
'id' => int 2
'user_id' => int 1
'total_days' => int 1
'total_eating' => int 6
'notes' => string '' (length=0)
'created' => string '2016-09-01' (length=10)
'eating_type' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
         array (size=6)
           'id' => int 7
           'diet_id' => int 2
           'eating_time' => string '8:00' (length=4)
           'eating_type' => string 'Breakfast' (length=10)
           'recommended_rate' => int 0
           'diet_food' => 
               array (size=0)
                   ...
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 8
          'diet_id' => int 2
          'eating_time' => string '12:00' (length=5)
          'eating_type' => string 'Lunch' (length=14)
          'recommended_rate' => int 0
          'diet_food' => 
              array (size=0)
                 ...
```

In the array the **diet_food** is empty even though I have data stored in the datababase.

### Diet Model

```
class Diet extends Model
{
    public $table = "diet_settings";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function eatingType(){
        return $this->hasMany(EatingType::class);
    }
}
```

### EatingType Model

```
class EatingType extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = "eating_types";

    public function dietFood(){
        return $this->hasMany(DietFood::class, 'id','eating_type_id');
    }
    public function diet(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Diet::class);
    }
}
```

### DietFood Model

```
class DietFood extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = "diet_food";

    public function eatingType(){
        return $this->belongsTo(EatingType::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe there is something to make eager and lazy (I am just know a lil at java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by following this guide about pivots: http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Also when you are outputting data it should be done like this:

```
$diets = Diet::with('eating')->get();
foreach($diets as $diet){
    var_dump($diet->eating->toArray());
}
```